# Getting a final object from an .each loop.

Tags: jquery, object, each

I'm using jquery to make a simple quiz. I'm trying to get the question, answer (content) and answer (index) into an object. Here is my code so far and a fiddle.

```
    $('.submit').on('click', function() {

        $('li[data-question]').each(function(i){

            question = $(this).attr('data-question');
            answer = $(this).find('input:checked').parent().text().trim();
            index = $(this).find('input:checked').parent().parent().parent().index() + 1;

            $('body').data(question, {
                "question":question,
                "index":index,
                "answer":answer
            });

            console.log( $('body').data() );

        });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oe6z9svq/2/

That works, but I want to just get the final object of responses out of it. Currently it steps through each question and makes an object for each one, adding one at a time.

How can I return(?) the final result as json then use it elsewhere?

Comment: Stick everything into an Array when looping.

Comment: Got it working using your suggestion, but is there a way to get the last .data iterations object from the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on MelancialUK's comment to put all the questions in an array:

```
$('.submit').on('click', function () {

    var questions = [];

    $('li[data-question]').each(function (i) {

        question = $(this).attr('data-question');
        answer = $(this).find('input:checked').parent().text().trim();
        index = $(this).find('input:checked').parent().parent().parent().index() + 1;

        questions.push({
            question: question,
            index: index,
            answer: answer
        });

    });

    $('body').data("questions", questions);
    console.log(questions);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oe6z9svq/3/

Comment: I initially used an array, but thought that .data would be better. I restructured my code a little with your advice and got it to where it needs to be. Thanks a lot. Curiously, is there a way to do it with just .data? As in get the last iterations object?